# What can I make with corn flake that is no longer crispy?

Tags: culinary-uses

I left the cornflake bag open for too long that it is not crispy anymore. Still taste good, but I wonder what can I do with it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think this is fine per [the culinary use question guidelines](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/a/741/1672) - in fact, one of the examples given there is stale bread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can crisp them up again in a hot oven for a few minutes (exact temperature not too important, spread them out thinly on a baking sheet and take them out before they burn).  I'd then go on to make a normal cornflake cake recipe of your liking straight away, to avoid having the same problem again.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe see how it does in the food processor for corn flake crumbs. Possible uses could be meatballs or meat pies or anywhere else you would want a filler.

Answer (score 3):

A nice thing might be [cereal milk](http://milkbarstore.com/main/menu/recipes-and-how-tos/) (made famous by Momofuku Milk Bar).

The cornflakes are toasted and steeped in milk with some brown sugar. Theres also [cornflake crunch](http://www.marthastewart.com/865366/cornflake-crunch) (both recipes are in the Milk Bar cookbook) -- clusters of toasted cornflakes with some sugar and milk powder and butter.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is close to Chris H except i found this for myself

Take a bit of butter on a pan.

Main point is to use a butter (home butter at best), dont use natural or flower oils that can be bought in a store. That way corn flakes reach nice aroma which natural oils can not reach.

Heat the pan up . After butter gets melt add corn flakes and roast them 3-5min.
Dont burn them. 
You will see that the cornflakes had now slightly different taste because of a butter.

Optionally add salt after you finish roasting.

Thing i should point out.

I have not tried this with "budget" corn flakes since they has different taste and structure against quality ones.

enjoy